# compactness and infimum

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, compactness

**Question:**
If $S$ is compact and $z_0 \not\in S$, prove that $Inf_{z∈S}|z − z_0| > 0$

**My Attempt:**
Since S in compact, and the element is considered as complex number, we can assume that $S$ is compact in $C$. Then $S$ is also closed and bounded at the same time. Since $S$ is closed, that means $z_0$ is not a limit point of $S$. That means, for some $\epsilon > 0 $, there exists a neighborhood of $z_0$ such that intersection between $N_{\epsilon}(z_0)$ and $S$ is empty, implying there exists a distance between $z_0$ and $S$. Thus $Inf_{z∈S}|z − z_0| > 0$ holds.

One thing I'm not sure about this proof is that whether it is legit to assume $S$ is compact in $C$ just because the element is given as complex number.
If you have any other ideas to share, it would be really grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your attempt is valid if $S$ is any closed non-empty subset of $\Bbb C$. Compact subsets of $\Bbb C$ are necessarily closed because $\Bbb C$ is a Hausdorff space.